# Initialize a variant r value reference in C++

Tags: c++, templates, variant

I have the following variant that I want to initialize with another rvalue reference of `Type1` or `Type2`.
`std::variant<Type1, Type2>&& myVariant;`

```
template<Type>
void function(Type&& t)
{
 // need to create a variant from t in myVariant
 std::variant<Type1, Type2>&& myVariant;

}
```

`func` is a template function so I don't know if `t` is `Type1` or `Type2`. How can I make `myVariant` be the variant version of `t`?

I have tried this, which doesn't work.

```
std::variant<Type1, Type2>&& myVariant = t;
```

I have `std::variant<Type1, Type2>&& myVariant(std::move(t));` which works but I want to confirm that's how I should be initializing it.

Comment: Why do you want an rvalue reference? Rvalue references are for values which are about to be (or have just been) moved.

Comment: yes, I want to move it in the next line.

Comment: There is no reason for the `variant` to be an rvalue reference. Just create a normal `variant` and move `t` into it: `std::variant<Type1, Type2> myVariant(std::move(t));` Then you can move the `variant` afterwards if needed.